# Custom hook is not a function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try and call a function from my custom hook I get back an error when the screen loads saying `setAuth` is not a function.

`useAuth.js`

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";
const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
export default useAuth;
```

`login.js`

```
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
...
const Login = () => {
 const { setAuth } = useAuth();
 ....
 setAuth({ email, password, accessToken });
 ...
 }
```

If I try and display `typeof(setAuth)` I get undifined.

Comment: isn't it because you export the hook as default? So in the `const` the brackets might not be needed?

Comment: @MartijnVissers same error even without the braces

Comment: Does it matter if the name is `setAuth` instead of the `useAuth` you defined?

Comment: Based on your example is a bit difficult to guess, but could you check if AuthProvider is actually being provided correctly? What happens if you use plain `useContext(AuthContext)` in Login component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your AuthContext has a setAuth function. Where you are calling your AuthContext.Provider you must provide setAuth function in the value prop

```
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ setAuth }}>
```

You can then access `setAuth`

```
const useAuth = () => {
 const { setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
 return setAuth
}
```

`login.js`

```
const Login = () => {
 const setAuth = useAuth();
 ....
 setAuth({ email, password, accessToken });
 ...
 }
```